# install 32 bit program from installer on 64 bit machine

Tags: installation, windows-installer

With some installers that I have (i.e. fiddler, hex workshop) I see that if I take the installer file to a 64 bit machine, it installs a 64 bit version of the program, but if I take the same installer file to a 32 bit machine, it installs the 32 bit version of that program.

My question is - how can I force the installer to install a 32 bit version of the program on a 64 bit machine?

Comment: You can do this by only providing 32 bit solution. This will work on 64´s to.For .NET solutions you have to specify x86 in your solution.

Comment: What do you mean by solution? I'm not talking about visual studio, but about just an installer file that I have (downloaded from the software's provider site)

Comment: I assumed you are talking about development. We cannot help you with existing software where only the installer exisist. This is not a programming question.

Comment: You need to contact the software vendor that built the installer and ask them  (or check their user guide) to see if there are any command line switches that allow you to force the installation of a 32 bit package on 64 bit machines. Usually such installers don't have this option and automatically decide which MSI (32 or 64 bit) to run in the background,  but maybe you're lucky.